# Get Department from dimension in AX 2012

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I want to get the department from the default dimension in AX 2012.

In the `LedgerJournalTrans->lines->FinancialDimension` I can fill the department but in the database for AX the default dimension is saved.

I'm working on SSRS reports d=so I want to get the department in SQL query.

Can anyone help me how to get the department and explain simply the relations

Thank you in advance and best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in SQL:

```
select DisplayValue from  DefaultDimensionView 
    where DefaultDimension = 1234567890
      and Name ='Department'
```

In X++:

```
select DisplayValue from defaultDimensionView 
    where defaultDimensionView.DefaultDimension == this.DefaultDimension
       && defaultDimensionView.Name == 'Department';
```

Comment: thank you and which view contain Offsetledgerdimension?

Comment: @klaas explanation is the answer for the ledger dimension, but if you are not familiar with the table structure here is the code :
    select DISPLAYVALUE from DIMENSIONATTRIBUTELEVELVALUEALLVIEW B 
 JOIN DIMENSIONATTRIBUTE A on A.RECID = B.DIMENSIONATTRIBUTE 
 where B.VALUECOMBINATIONRECID = 987654321 and A.NAME =   'Department'

Comment: You are correct, my answer is for ledger dimension, not default dimension. I would refrain from hardcoding the name for "dimension' though and create a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit: as pointed out this is for ledger dimension and not default dimension, but I'll leave it for info:*

Check out the `DimensionAttributeLevelValueAllView` view. It contains all the data you need.

- Filter on the `DimensionAttributeValueGroup` field using the ledgerdimension recid from ledgerjournaltrans.
- The `DisplayValue` contains the value of the dimension
- The `DimensionAttribute` field refers to the dimension, for example the department, and it links to the `DimensionAttribute` table. This is setup so you'll have to store the recid for the department somewhere and join with this setup field. Otherwise there is no way to 'know' which of those dimensions the department dimension is.

Answer (score 0):

see: [How to set a single dimension value in AX 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984449/how-to-set-a-single-dimension-value-in-ax-2012)

has a good whitepaper mentioned