# Edit brand dimension on released product

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I would like to change the brand dimension on some released products via a query.

I have noticed the field `DimensionValue1` within the `Financial Dimension Group`

What is the best way to `SELECT` this Financial Dimension -> Brand, so i can update the value?

I have tried to follow the relations of the tables, but i can't find the right value.

Comment: Did you take a look at [How to set a single dimension value in AX 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984449/how-to-set-a-single-dimension-value-in-ax-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A released product carries a "DefaultDimension". A defaultdimenson is a unique combination of the financial dimensions used in the current account structure (e.g. Cost Centre, Department, Brand etc.).

To update a single dimension value (brand) in the defaultdimension, I would recommend writing an X++ job.

There are many helper classes available to allow you to do this. DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage, DimensionAttribute, and DimensionAttributeValue are a good place to start. Between the three methods below, you should be able to find/create a new defaultDimension value to store with your Released Product.

```
DimensionAttributeValueSetStorage::find(defaultDimension);
DimensionAttribute::findByName('Brand');
DimensionAttributeValue::findByDimensionAttributeAndValue( dimensionAttribute, stringValueOfKeyColumn, forUpdateBoolean, createIfReqdBoolean)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check `DimensionAttributeBalueSetItem` and `DimensionAttributeBalueSet` **Tables**, but this is complex, You'll have to create a fairly complex procedure to update the value.

regards,

Answer (score 1):

In following blog post there is a good schema that you need to understand to work with the Financial Dimensions:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ax_gfm_framework_team_blog/2013/02/15/ledger-account-combinations-part-1-dimensions/

It could be helpful.

Best Regards,
Kristian